# How to fetch only n number of rows in subquery to compare the fetched columns to a main query (in oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I want to fetch last three invoices payment due date  and compare it with payment date and need to select only those customers who satisfies that condition i try to achieve this like below for sample but it is not giving desired output.

I want to check due dates for all last three invoices and compare it with payment date for all last three invoices so sorting the rows by last modified in subquery and trying to do it for only last three per customer using rownum >= 3

But issue is i am only getting three rows i.e. rownum >= 3 is getting applied for whole query not just for inner one

```
select c.cust_node_id
  from payment pay
  inner join (select i.payment_due_date as pay_due_date,
                     cnh.customer_node_id as cust_node_id,
                     i.invoice_id as inv_id
                from invoice i
                inner join customer_node_history cnh
                  on i.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id and
                     i.current_due = 0 and
                     rownum >= 3 and
                     cnh.customer_node_type_id = customer_node_type_id
                order by last_modified) c
    on pay.invoice_id = c.invoice_id and
       c.pay_due_date <= pay.payment_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the find the customers with at least 3 payments dates past the due date then join the tables and aggregate and add a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
select c.cust_node_id
from   payment p
       inner join invoice i
       on     i.invoice_id   =  p.invoice_id
          and i.pay_due_date <= p.payment_date
       inner join customer_node_history cnh
       on     i.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id
          and cnh.customer_node_type_id = customer_node_type_id
GROUP BY c.cust_node_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```